# Ember Data error when deleting model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an Ember-cli app (v2.1), and I'm having an issue with Ember Data when deleting a record from my **blog** model. Here's the code I'm calling for the deletion:

```
deleteBlog (blog) {
  this.store.findRecord('blog', blog.get('id')).then(blog => {
    blog.destroyRecord();
  });
}
```

As expected, Ember Data makes the DELETE request, which works perfectly with my express.js backend service.

The **only** problem is that the record does not get removed from the Ember Data store, and I get the following error message:

Error: Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on my-app@model:blog::ember529:56455037f9cf29a325ae72b9 while in state root.deleted.inFlight

I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Why would you try to retrieve the blog object from the store when you seem to already have it in the variable `blog`?

Comment: `destroyRecord` is asynchronous (because of the implicit save), so try hanging a `then` off it and continuing with your processing from there.

Comment: @torazaburo It looks like pulling the record twice like that was actually causing the error. Thanks for making me think!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in trying to select the model using an instance of the model that I already had. Changing it to a simple:

```
 deleteBlog (blog) {
   blog.destroyRecord();
 }
```

got rid of the error! Thanks again to @torazaboro for helping me to take a closer look at the mistake.

Comment: This is the correct answer - I was also stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 deleteBlog (blog) {
   this.store.findRecord('blog', blog.get('id')).then(function(blog) {
      blog.deleteRecord(); // => remove blog from the store
      blog.save(); // => DELETE request
    });
}
```

But this is supposed to do the same as `blog.destroyRecord();` so it may not work.

What is probably happenning is that if you have a request to the server in-flight and you delete the model then you get an exception `Attempted to handle event` pushedData `on model while in state root.deleted.uncommitted`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was actually doing that first, and was getting the same error.

Comment: `destroyRecord` just calls `deleteRecord` followed by `save`